# stuck on Bootloop twrp not installing

Tags: twrp, fastboot, boot-loop, bootloader, realme

HI guys my phone is stuck on fastboot,
its showing the current image(boot/recovery) have been destroyed and can not boot
pressing volume + power put it into fastboot and it shows in adb "fastboot devices" i tried to install custom recovery with "fastboot boot recovery.img" and its not working picture attached and i tried to boot img but same error shows FAILD(remote: unknow command)[image]

Comment: Please do not post console output as screen-shot. You can simply copy the console content and paste it into your question.

Comment: fastboot boot is disabled on some devices, only fastboot flash will work